# How to calculate the change in angle due to the righting moment of a ship?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, angular-velocity, buoyancy

I trying to calculate how the forces on a boat (initially out of equilibrium) work to right it. The cross section of the boat is a convex polygon and constant throughout its length. I can find the center of mass, $G$, and hence the weight of the boat, and for a given water level I can find the center of buoyancy, $B$, and hence the buoyant force due to the displaced water (the boat has a uniform density less than that of water).

[image: Force diagram for boat out of equilibrium]

My question is: am I correct to take the torque around $G$ to be $\boldsymbol{\tau} = \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{F}_b$ and then calculate the instantaneous change in angular velocity about $G$ as
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\omega}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\boldsymbol{\tau}}{I}
$$
where $I$ is the moment of inertia of the boat about $G$? Here I take it that the component of $\boldsymbol{F}_b$ perpendicular to $r$ is responsible for the torque; leaving a parallel component: what happens to this component of $\boldsymbol{F}_b$ parallel to $r$? Do I add it to $\boldsymbol{F}_g$ to give the change in linear momentum of the boat?

Comment: It acts along the line joining B and G. Yes it changes the linear momentum.

Comment: Non-perpendicular to what? Buoyancy force is vertical

Comment: @Ben51 Non-perpendicular (ie parallel) to $r$, the line joining G and B. The perpendicular component to this line provides the turning moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two relationships to consider.  (1) The equation of motion for the center of mass (CM), and (2) the equation for rotation about the CM.

For motion of the CM, $\vec F_b - \vec F_g = m\vec a$ where $\vec a$ is the acceleration of the CM taking upward as positive, and $m$ is the total mass of the boat.  Assuming the boat can only rotate about an axis into the page, as you say you take the CM as the origin and $\vec r \times \vec F_b = \vec \tau =  I d \vec \omega/dt$ for rotation around an axis through the CM ($\vec \omega$ is into the page through the CM).  As you say, the component of $\vec F_b$  perpendicular to $\vec r$ contributes to the magnitude of the torque.  (For the CM moving, you should always take the torque about the CM , as shown in texts on mechanics, such as Mechanics by Symon and Classical Mechanics by Goldstein.)

As the equation of motion for the CM indicates, you add the vectors $\vec F_b$ and $-\vec F_g$ to evaluate the motion for the CM.  Both these vectors are only in the vertical direction, so the magnitude of the acceleration upward of the CM is $a = {{F_b - F_g} \over m}$.

*All of $F_b$ contributes to counter $F_g$, not just the component of $\vec F_b$ parallel to $\vec r$.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm still a little bit confused, however. In your last paragraph (the case of the boat in equilibrium), do you mean that there is no component of $\boldsymbol{F}_b$ perpendicular to $\boldsymbol{r}$? (for in this case $G$ and $B$ lie on a vertical line). In the non-equilibrium case, I don't see how all of $\boldsymbol{F}_b$ can counter $\boldsymbol{F}_g$ and yet leave a component to act as a turning moment: I must be misunderstanding something somewhere.

Comment: The last paragraph had an error, sorry; it should say there is no component of Fb perpendicular to r in equilibrium, as you say. In equilibrium (no net torque, no net force) all of vector Fb is parallel to vector r (Fb is always vertically upward). I deleted the part with the error. For the non-equilibrium case for the torque to not be zero, there must be a component of Fb perpendicular to r; if Fb equals Fg in magnitude the CM does not move but the boat turns due to the torque . The CM motion is due to net force, the rotation is due to net torque. –